# \rule + memoir in \title Paragraph ended before \reserved@a was complete

Tags: memoir, titles, rules

I'm trying to make my customized title, but error happen with memoir (and not with article).

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\makeatletter
\def\printtitle{%                       
    {\centering \@title\par}}
\makeatother
\title{ The first text line \rule{10cm}{.5pt} the second text line }
\begin{document}
    \printtitle
\end{document}
```

The result:

```
! Argument of \reserved@a has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
            \par 
l.7 ...ne \rule{10cm}{.5pt} the second text line }
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Usually this should be solvable by typing `\protect\rule`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Differently from the `article` class, in `memoir` the argument to `\title` is a moving argument, so fragile commands in it need to be preceded by `\protect`; among them is `\rule`.

Note also that `memoir` defines `\thetitle` that's preferable to `\@title` for doing things with the title in the document. The difference is that `\@title` also keeps possible `\thanks`, whereas `\thetitle` will remove them.

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\newcommand\printtitle{{\centering \thetitle\par}}
% or
%\makeatletter
%\newcommand\printtitle{{\centering \@title\par}}
%\makeatother

\title{The first text line\\ \protect\rule{10cm}{.5pt}\\ the second text line}

\begin{document}

\printtitle

\end{document}
```

[image]

By the way, it's precisely the need to define `\thetitle` the cause that makes the argument to `\title` a moving one.